# What would cause my sink to back up and my dishwasher pipe to overflow?

Tags: drain, dishwasher, garbage-disposal

So I installed a new disposal and connected the dishwasher directly to the disposal. I put a stopper in the second drain pipe the dishwasher was draining to and all has been ok. Recently, the sink isnt draining, I tried snaking, plunging, and removed and reinstalled the pipes. I removed the plug on the second drain pipe under the sink, but now everything is overflowing and spilling up under my sink. Any suggestions on what else I could do here? This is my last step before biting the bullet and calling a plumber.

Comment: do you have a street clean-out before the drain exits the building?

Comment: shop-vac it?  How long of a snake did you stick down it?  That's typically enough...does anything else not drain?

Answer (score 1):

Call the plumber.  That kind of backing up indicates a problem down the line that is not easily addressed.